# Is there any way to open a new tab in the user manually opened chrome session?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open a new tab in chrome using python selenium. It can be done in the Chrome session which is opened by python. But i have a scenario where user will have chrome opened with some URLs and then they will run automation which should open a new tab in the user opened chrome session. Is there any way to do that? Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Comment: i can see many solutions there but nothing worked. Still checking