# Connecting with selenium to a browser PID

Tags: selenium, remote-debugging

I am using Edge (in IE mode) to run a test.  For quite a while we have been having a problem when we click on one link and a new Edge window comes up, selenium cannot find the new Window handle.  We have had to use something like Test Complete to access the window.  (We can't use Robot as that does not work on Jenkins).

I looked at the task manager, and after the click there is a new msedge.exe task (in this instance PID 14328 but that will change each time).

I want to open a new Edge browser (with a new driver) and see whether I can attach to that Edge browser using the PID.  I have a feeling this may work?

I found this:

[Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

but this does not mention anything about a pid.  It seems you open a new driver and get the session id of the driver, and the url, and set it back.  I want to be able to connect to a new PID. I am hoping this may be able to solve the problem, but I am not sure.  Is there a way to do this?

I am doing this with Java via Eclipse.