# How to use Selenium in already exist browser?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I ask this question and receive some link.

[Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

But this answer is too old to use in nowatimes.

Also i use Selenium version 4.

Is there any method to manipulate exist broswer?

Comment: Answers posted in the linked questions are from last year, one of them is less than 3 months old. Are they all deprecated now..?

Comment: @alex Sorry, But it must use chrome debugging mode.
i want to manipulate original chrome