# Python selenium script can't connect to browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

### Example

This is a script that should be able to connect to the browser that was launched with debug options in the command prompt. As I provide later I'm no longer able to connect to the remote browser at 127.0.0.1:9222." I've tried searching for a solution, but I haven't found one that works.

*Launching browser in with debug port*

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

*Python script*

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options

edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', '127.0.0.1:9222')

driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options)
driver.get(youtube.com)
printf(driver.title)
```

---

### Problem

For some reason, my code can no longer connect to the browser launched by the command mentioned. This is an error message Im facing.

*part of the error message*

```py
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to microsoft edge at 127.0.0.1:9222 **from chrome not reachable **
```

*full error message*

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Plocha\záložky\msedge - running\Try 18.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to microsoft edge at 127.0.0.1:9222
from chrome not reachable
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperties::SetProperty [0x00007FF72EE616C2+15186]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72EDFA212+827554]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72EABEBF3]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72EAAEC8A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72EAF013D]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72EAE5D4A]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72EB29C56]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72EB21D23]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72EAF3B80]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72EAF2B0E]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72EAF4344]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperties::SetProperty [0x00007FF72ECDC3B0+182752]
    (No symbol) [0x00007FF72EBB0095]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72ED3A6EA+42362]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72ED3D425+53941]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::ILogManager::DispatchEventBroadcast [0x00007FF72F058AB3+1456595]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72EE0276A+861690]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72EE07854+882404]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72EE079AC+882748]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::EventProperty [0x00007FF72EE1097E+919566]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FF8D3C726BD+29]
    RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FF8D5A6DFB8+40]
```

**What have I tried?**

There are many tutorials on using python and chrome, but not many are for an edge. Here are some samples of things I've tried:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zrx8FSEo9lk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGaU0OgtbNk&t=181s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pZdMsLKAjs4&t=271s
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=710#c3
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/automated-browser-testing-with-edge-and-selenium-in-python/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session
```

Be patient, thanks.