# how to navigate through an opened page in browser

Tags: python

Hi everyone I have access to a page, it is already opened in my chrome browser, I now I could to scrape it using selenium o bs4.

My question  if there is any tool in python allow me read the opened page, not requests method is necessary, because it is already open in this case. I need some light about it. Thks

Comment: [Seems possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session). You can also save the page and parse the html source or save all as HAR and parse that json.

Comment: i think he want do somting like Solve captcha with reading the page i didnt find anythink use full for that

Comment: This is very vague.. what are you trying to read? What do you need returned??

Comment: @Caleb-Carson, let me explain better, I have a page that need user and password to access and  need to a code, the code change every 8 hours, but if the page is open, it is not necessary change it , so I want to automatize  scrapping some details from web. I know how to do that with bs but as code is changing Im looking for the way to get the info from my browser not from request

Comment: Something you can do using Selenium is use the find_element_by_name() function with selenium. Use the inspect element to determine what the password and username fields are called. Then you can use the send_keys() function to send the username and password to those fields. Not sure if this is what you are looking for exactly but it should help get you started.

Comment: that I really need is to read  browse open window in  computer