# excel VBA selenium: fill in user and password

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am developing an Excel application to connect to a data provider.

Is it possible to fill in the username and password fields with the data previously saved in the browser (Edge) without having to define the username and password in the VBA code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, by default, Selenium will create a new anonymous session of your browser. If you want to use the saved passwords from your current session, you'd need to open a tab in an existing browser.

Knowing that, you can have a look at this question to get started:
[Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)