# Reconnect to an already open Selenium Webdriver to do more actions in a seperate python function

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

So I have a use case where the system I'm trying to connect to requires a full sign in and text message validation every time a new browser is launched. I want to have the user log in once and then until they close that browser window they can continue to send automation to the same window.

**First function opens the site and saves some session details, the user could then log in, etc. Currently I'm saving the command_executor._url and the sesion_id for future use to a json**

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json


url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"

opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("detach",True)


swd = Chrome(options=opt)
swd.get(url)


session = {'url':swd.command_executor._url,'id':swd.session_id}

with open('session.json','w') as file:
    json.dump(session,file)
```

**Second function I'd like to be able to grab the existing window and do some actions.**

```
from selenium.webdriver import Remote
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import json

with open("session.json","r") as file:
    session = json.load(file)

opt = Options()
opt.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress",session['url'])

swd = Remote(command_executor=session['url'],options=opt)

#do some actions 

swd.quit()
```

**It seems like I'm doing something wrong but I have no idea what to change. I know there a few threads talking about this but it seems like all of them are out of date or for different situations**

**Here is the error i'm getting:**

raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=#####): Max retries exceeded with url: /session (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Selenium interact with an existing browser session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session)

Comment: It seems like stuff has changed since then - the desired_capabilities={} doesnt seem to exist anymore. This post was one of my starting points.