# How to connect Selenium 4 to an existing chrome browser session

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

As I am testing out my selenium scripts and hit an error the browser stays open. I want Selenium to connect to that existing open browser session so I can debug what went wrong instead of opening a new session and logginn in etc again.

I have tried to follow answers on here for selenium 3 but haven't suceeded.
[previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session#:%7E:text=This%20is%20a%20pretty%20old,session%2Dselenium%2Djava%2F.)

I have tried to use experimental options

```
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:9222")
```

and also changing the port of the intial browser with service

```
service = Service(port="8989)
```

and then trying to select it with a debugger address

```
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:8989")
```

I believe these are for Selenium 3. Can anybody help me with a **solution for Selenium 4.12**?

Full code below:

```
# Work on existing broswer 
# Import Selenium 4 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import (
    NoSuchElementException,
    TimeoutException,
    ElementClickInterceptedException,
)

# General Imports
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import os

# Start Webdriver

options = Options()

# Download directly to folder & disable safe brower queries on download
preferences = {
    "download.default_directory": r"C:\................",
    "safebrowsing.enabled": True,
    "download.prompt_for_download": False,
    "download.directory_upgrade": True,
    "profile.password_manager_enabled": False,
    "credentials_enable_service": False,
}

options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--disable-web-security")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress","localhost:9222")

service = Service()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```