How can I get Selenium to read my open page in Python?
I can't get Selenium to read the page I left open, every time I try on of the commands from the documentation, it doesn't recognize the .driver.
Every time I use my own configs, it opens a new page.
There's a question relatively similar, but mine's in Chrome, not Firefox.
I tried this code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


print(driver.current_url)

url = driver.current_url
driver = driver.title
download_speed = url.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value="download-speed")
download_speed = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, value="download-speed")
print(download_speed)
driver.close()


Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example Your code, as shown, is not runnable

selenium does not work the way you think: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344776/can-selenium-interact-with-an-existing-browser-session

That's weird, the code is runnable for me.
Thanks Daniele, your comment really helped.
